# Buffered Methods in Java for writing Objects in Files?

Tags: java, object, io

I wanted to know if its possible or there is some library for having buffered I/O methods for writing/reading objects in java (ObjectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream).

Thanks in advance for your help.
Besnik.

Answer (score 6):

Just create a `BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`/`FileInputStream`, then pass that to the constructor of the `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream`.

If that's not what you're after, please clarify your question.